# Tor doesn't allow hidden services

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, windows, firefox

For testing reasons, I have to run tor without torbrowser bundle on windows.

I do the following:

```
1) Open cmd prompt windows
2) chdir to the directory where tor.exe is
3) Execute cmd line: tor.exe
```

If I start Firefox, and edit the proxy settings to 127.0.0.1 and port 9050, I am able to surf internet, but I don't know why I can't access to .onion sites (hidden services). But if I start the tor browser bundle, I can do it. What can I do?

Comment: This is almost definitely answered under a question about why you shouldn't use other browsers with tor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between the Tor proxy and the Browser Bundle?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10691/whats-the-difference-between-the-tor-proxy-and-the-browser-bundle)